# Dónde puedo cambiar la ruta a la que te redirecciona el Auth de Laravel /home en Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

Estoy buscando en el controlador de Auth y me muestra `protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;`y hace referencia a la ruta /home

Comment: Debes editar la constante `HOME` ubicada en `RouteServiceProvider`. Otra opción es sobrescribir el método `authenticated()` en tu LoginController

Comment: Cuál permance aún despues que ejecute composer install en el servidor?

Comment: Yo estuve haciendo clic derecho para ver si me llavaba `RouteServiceProvider` y no lo hizo, ahora la ubico.

Comment: uizás el trasnocho jaja están en Providers gracias!

Comment: @Joseph deberías responder a tu propia pregunta para evitar que se quede abierta y asi otros encuentren la solución

Comment: Gracias lo haré, también revisar anteriores y si dejé de calificar alguna.

Comment: gracias a ambos!

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví con la respuesta de L. Flor, editando la constante `HOME` ubicada en `RouteServiceProvider`

Answer (score 1):

Usando el método *authenticated* en el controlador *auth/LoginController*

Ejemplo redirección según el rol del usuario

```
    protected function authenticated()
    {
        $usuario = \App\User::find(auth()->user()->id);
        if(($usuario->hasRole('administrador'))){
            return  redirect()->route('administracion.index');
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sería bueno indicarle sobre este método `hasRole` ya que ningún paquete de autenticación de Laravel lo trae